# Springboot-Admin recognizes client apps as down frequently

Tags: spring-boot-admin

we have approximately 20 springboot applications registering themselves in a springbootadmin-server.

Whenever those apps achive a higher load volume, the springboot-admin servers periodic requests time out and he considers the app "down". Shortly after, as soon as the load reduces on the client, it is recognized as up again.

What would be the best practise to reduce the false "down" messages on the server:

- increasing the timeout of the `spring.boot.admin.monitor.timeout.*` properties
- tune the client side application server threadpools for the request
- separate the actuator endpoint to a seperate threadpool (is that even possible?)

thanks and regards
Marc